# Google cloud build unexpected char : in cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml, git-submodules, google-cloud-build

I am getting the following error in my google cloud build

```
Failed to trigger build: failed unmarshalling build config cloudbuild.yaml: yaml: line 12: could not find expected ':'
```

I can not pinpoint where exactly I am missing `:` in my `cloudbuild.yaml` file

```
steps:
  # Install
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["install"]
  # Update submodules
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
      git config -f .gitmodules submodule.myprojectsubmodule.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/github_myprojectsubmodule
      git submodule init
      git submodule update
  # Lint
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "lint"]
  # Test
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "test"]
  # Build
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args:
      - kms
      - decrypt
      - --ciphertext-file=.env.enc
      - --plaintext-file=.env
      - --location=global
      - --keyring=myproject
      - --key=cloudbuild-env
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "build"]
  # Deploy
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm"
    args: ["run", "deploy"]
```

I have added `# Update submodules` step using the following comment https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/26#issuecomment-463465138

Comment: Quotes are missing for `# Build \n - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud`... could be the cause ?

Comment: That is not the error message I am receiving. It is on line no. 12. However, quotes do not matter in the `- name` tag.

Comment: ok. it's true sorry. I try again ;-).  `git` commands should be aligned under the pipe symbol. I check your yaml format with https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator, before and after the correction.

Comment: Right. They should be aligned with the pipe symbol. You can put your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: See also ... https://medium.com/@davidstanke/mastering-google-cloud-build-config-syntax-8c3024607daf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be a valid `yaml` format, the `git` commands should be correctly aligned under the `|` symbol in **Update submodules** section.

```
# Update submodules
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/git"
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
      - "-c"
      - |
        git config -f .gitmodules submodule.myprojectsubmodule.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/myproject/r/github_myprojectsubmodule
        git submodule init
        git submodule update
```

A YAML validator could be useful in this case, for example https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator.